# Run script on boot

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to run a .sh script ONCE when I boot? I know about the init.d folders, but there seems to be some weird special layout you must use for scripts there.

I only want to run two quick lines of code, nothing huge. I'm running the latest Raspbian.

Any tips?

Comment: We don't consider RPis to be servers within the meaning of ServerFault. We consider [su], [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se] to be better suited to the enthusiast nature of this device.

Comment: I don't know if it works in Raspbian, but some crontabs allow you to specify time as `@reboot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **NOT** standard compliant, but it works:

Create a new file in /etc/init.d -->

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
start)
    yourcodehere 
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

then set the executable bit and remove all other permissions:
`chmod 700 /etc/init.d/filename`

and then configure your service to autostart: `update-rc.d filename defaults`